# TypeScript with jszip.d.ts

Tags: c#, typescript, jszip

I want to use jszip to get file into ZIP, but it doesn't work.
When I try to load jszip.d.ts in Solution, it showed error.
[image]
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type
How can I correct it?
I use VS2015, tsc1.8, TypeScriptTool2.0.6